# Checking which radio button is selected in PHP

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I have an HTML page that contains two radio buttons ("yes" and "no") along with a submit button.

How can I specify that I want to execute a PostgreSQL query ONLY if the submit button is pressed AND the "yes" radio button is selected?

Answer (score 1):

Your radio buttons need to have the same `name`, so check the value that is submitted for that field:

```
if ($_POST['radio'] == 'Yes')
{
    // Execute query
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given HTML like this

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
    <label for="yesno_yes">
        <input type="radio" name="yesno" value="yes" id="yesno_yes"> Yes
    </label>
    <label for="yesno_no">
        <input type="radio" name="yesno" value="no" id="yesno_no"> No
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You can check using this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_btn'], $_POST['yesno']) && $_POST['yesno'] == 'yes') {
    // do stuff here
}
```